# PostgreSQL performance: Is an index on a NOT NULL column faster than a NOT NULL column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, null

In a production table of a couple of tens of millions records, we found out that we have an (indexed) string column that in or domain logic is never NULL. However, this column currently is not enforced to be NOT NULL in the schema.

Now we are wondering: Is there a performance difference between querying an indexed (NULL allowed) column vs an indexed NOT NULL column? Or does it not really matter? Does the way the index is (/can be) stored inside Postgres differ between these two cases?

Comment: I don't believe there is any performance difference on a b-tree index.  Postgres separates out the `NULL` values anyway in the index.  If there aren't any, then the header portion will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is completely irrelevant. There is no special treatment for `NULL` values in indexes. The only exception is that a `UNIQUE` index can contain several `NULL`s, but that has no performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

An index holds the list of values of the column(s) specified.  If there are `NULL` values in the column, they will not be included in the index.  The `NOT NULL` constraint is simply a definition of what is allowed in the table, and does not affect the performance of the scanning the index (unless, of course, the schema is poorly designed and you specify `NOT NULL` for the column and then you put values of 0 or 'undefined` all over that column when you shouldn't -- that would pad the index with a bunch of useless values).

In short, `NOT NULL` simply limits the kinds of values that go in the table, not in the index, so index performance *generally* won't be affected.